# unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' while trying to get data in multiple sheets of Excel

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I am trying to get data in multiple sheets of Excel. Now with the code I got at the moment im getting the error: `unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException  occurred in mscorlib.dll' Additional information: Select method of Range class failed`. I get the error at the second time it runs in the for-loop.

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        xlexcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        xlexcel.Visible = true;
        xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Add();
        for (int i = 0; i < comboBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            xlWorkBook.Sheets.Add();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < comboBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            copyAlltoClipboard(); //this copies data to the clipboard
            xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(i+1);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range CR = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
            CR.Select(); //error is here
            xlWorkSheet.PasteSpecial(CR, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);
        }
```

Does anyone know why this code isnt working?

Comment: This problem is probably, because after it pastes the first values in the first sheet, it still has the selection of those values in excel. And then in the second loop, it tries to paste the values of the clipboard on those values

Comment: As a side note: Yo don't need to use the clipboard, you can select a range and assign to the array of that range. I don't remeber how to do it, but it is possible und vastly superior

Comment: @ChristianSauer Thanks for the side note, I still didnt fix the problem with  `SendKeys.Send("{ESC}");` or 
                `xlexcel.CutCopyMode = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCutCopyMode)0;`